# Suspicious popup and 'Yellow Booster' installation

Tags: malware, popup

A pop-up appeared on my phone stating:

> **Warning**
>
> You only have to install a Great App to get your phone fully functioned.

The only option I am given is "Confirm."I accidentally hit the confirm button and another popup appeared stating that the install was blocked. It appears that the initial pop up is powered by the "Yellow Booster" app. I tried restarting my phone but it reappeared again.

How do I avoid this, as it seems very suspicious to me.

[image: suspicious app]

[image: yellow booster]

Comment: Give us a relevant screenshot. This popup, when does it appear? when using a browser?

Comment: I was using my broswer the first time, the second I was trying to scan for malware, which can be seen in the screenshot.

Comment: As you have guessed, don't let them install the app for now (i.e. don't enable 'allow unknown source').

Comment: On a (un)related note, what is the app on the background that says 'Full Scan'? Does the popup always appear when you access it?

Comment: I installed the 360 Security app  right after I got the pop up to check for any viruses. The pop up reappears shortly after it is blocked. How can I prevent it from trying to install altogether?

Comment: When that popup/dialog (the one with warning) appears again, can you execute the commands `adb shell dumpsys window windows` and `adb shell dumpsys activity activities` and store the output somewhere safe? Use a text paste service, such as pastebin.com to share the output from those commands. You're going to need [tag:adb] installed and [tag:usb-debugging] activated.

Comment: @user168160 OP, you need to perform a big cleanup in order to bust unnecessary apps (such as the 360 thingy). Remember that Android cannot be infected by viruses (and yes, Mr. Izzy, this time I mean viruses for real), but only from **malware**, which comes in the form of apps. My recommendation is to start uninstalling even remotely suspicious software.

Comment: Don't use such antivirus apps or task killers like clean master....it's totally useless on Android and drains more battery I think that yellow booster is an adware app which can cause annoyance.

Comment: My answer may help: [Apps trying to install in background](http://android.stackexchange.com/a/145118)

Comment: @Firelord Was just about to refer them to that answer, very intuitive and helpful answer.

Comment: @MichaelNancarrow Thank you. Did you somehow come across this Yellow Booster scam as well? If yes, please share your findings in an answer.

Comment: For me uninstalling `Assistant for Android by AA Mobile` fixed this issue.