# "Warning - You only have to install a Great App to get your phone fully functioned." Keeps popping up

Tags: malware, verizon, antivirus

It looks like this same thing happened to a user 2 months ago, but I can not reply to that question: [Suspicious popup and 'Yellow Booster' installation](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/146133/suspicious-popup-and-yellow-booster-installation).  This thing goes away for hours, so we don't ever really know if it's gone, and then it pops back up.  Was this ever solved?  If anyone has found a solution, we would appreciate it.

On a different Droid forum, a lot of us started getting this problem recently. I have noticed a lot of us are on Verizon and on fairly new phones.  Personally, I am on a HTC 10, but other users are getting this pop up on Samsung and LG phones as well.  If anyone has anything that could help, I would greatly appreciate it!

Comment: I had this problem on a Cricket LG phone and it went away after uninstalling `Assistant for Android by AA Mobile`.

Comment: create download_1 folder where download folder exists . actually malware / ad it tries to create folder download_1 ..if exists it stops ..worked for me ..also scan using malware bytes ..or disable (Force Stop and then disable )PackageInstaller in system apps

Answer (score 4):

I went through this same problem. 
Here is the solution:

- First boot to safe mode:

  - Press the power button. A Power Off popup will show. Long press the Power Off popup. It will ask if you if you want to boot in safe mode. Press yes.
- After starting in safe mode, goto Settings > Apps and scroll down to the bottom to find Yellow Booster App. On clicking, you will see a screen with details of the App. Press Uninstall and you will be able to successfully uninstall. Note that, while you can reach this screen normally from setting, you can't press uninstall until you are in safe mode.
- As always, take effort to find other apps that are suspicious and remove them.
- Yellow booster is also known to sometimes have Device Administrator privileges. If it added itself as one, remove it as well. You can't remove that in non-safe mode.

Comment: Thanks but the Yellow Booster does not show up on my list of apps.  Would it be under a different name?

Comment: As part of the process I also removed the swift wifi app, which somehow was also installed. I wasn't sure how and when it was installed. I also removed that. Do you also **accidentally** have this app too?

Answer (score 3):

I had this exact issue, along with a lock screen that appeared whenever I started charging (blue background with bubbles).

The charging screen went away when I **uninstalled Flash Keyboard,** and I haven't see the Yellow Booster dialog since.

Comment: As a follow-up, several days have passed now and no further pop-ups have occurred.  Flash Keyboard was the only application I uninstalled, so I think it was the source of the problem for me.

Answer (score 0):

So far I was able to stop it for 18hrs from popping up. I tried three different Antivirus apps all came up with nothing and the pop up happened while they were running. What I did next was clear data cache and it stopped popping up from 12:45 yesterday until 6ish this morning when I got up and checked my phone it was the first thing I saw. So I did the whole data cache deletion again and then removed the Keyboard thing people were talking about in the other thread. So far it hasn't popped up again. But like I said nearly 18 hours passed from the last time I "fixed" the issue.

If anyone has any info please share it!

Verizon tech was no assistance they just kept telling me I installed the trojan with an app I downloaded which I hadn't downloaded anything within 24hrs of it occurring. And seeing as how everyone had different ANDROID devices and Cell carriers (Verizon, T-Mobile, Etc.) it is likely not one specific app, but rather a software hack with the new update that came out last week. My phone had just updated the day before this whole thing started.

Again I have mitigated the issue by clearing Data cache files but it only lasted 18hrs yesterday and so far 8hrs and counting today.

***UPDATE***
Yes, as mentioned in other posts "Flash Keyboard" is a legit app from the app store but it allows "malware" capabilities to happen on your device. It gives itself administrator rights and causes these pop-ups to occur. The simplest way to remove it is to use AVG or AVAST cleaner to fully uninstall it and all hidden files. So far it has been over 4 days and no pop-ups. Sorry for the delay in updating, I was watching to see if anything popped up again.

Comment: If that solved your issue, could you please [edit] your post and include some details on "this keyboard thing people were talking about"? Without knowing what exactly that is, it isn't very helpful :) Is it maybe "Flash Keyboard", as mentioned in [this answer](http://android.stackexchange.com/a/154943/16575)?

Answer (score 0):

Ok guys, thanks for the help, it seems to have been cleared from my phone now.  I did not have Yellow Booster or Swift Wifi listed in my applications manager, but I did have Flash Keyboard listed.  I uninstalled it and have not gotten the pop up since then.  I removed the Flash Keyboard on Sunday, it's now Thursday and I haven't had any issues so far *knocks on wood*

I'm not sure how the Flash Keyboard got installed in the first place.  I certainly didn't download it, it wasn't pre-installed on my HTC 10 either.  Does anyone know if there's a way to stop Google Play from installing apps without my permission?